# How to get more than one value from subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 result set which are:

***result_1:***

> ```
> | reportCard | exam | lessonType | lesson |
> |------------|------|------------|--------|
> |reportCard_1|exam_1|lessonType_1|lesson_1|
> |reportCard_1|exam_2|lessonType_1|lesson_2|
> |reportCard_1|exam_3|lessonType_1|lesson_3|
> |reportCard_1|exam_4|lessonType_1|lesson_4|
> ```

***result_2:***

> ```
> | reportCard | lessonType |
> |------------|------------|
> |reportCard_1|lessonType_1|
> |reportCard_1|lessonType_2|
> ```

now I need this result as a text:

> lessonType_1; lesson_1... lesson_2... lesson_3... lesson_4...
>
> lessonType_2; lesson_1... lesson_2... lesson_3... lesson_4...

because lessons are more than lessonTypes and lessons depends on lessonTypes I use a subquery which is like this:

```
select lessonType.title+
       char(10)+
       (
        select lesson.title'+...
        from
        ...
       )
from
...
```

unfortunately this error occurred:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

but actually I need my subquery returns more than one value.
any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you can achieve what you're looking for if you search for the term "STUFF FOR XML PATH". Either that, or you're trying to PIVOT - it's not 100% clear to me which you want.

Comment: @ZLK thanks man you were right I searched for that and it kind of helped me. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are looking for some group concatenation of each lesson in a given lesson type.  SQL Server does not have a `GROUP_CONCAT()` function like MySQL, but you can simulate it using `STUFF()`:

```
SELECT
    t1.lessonType,
    STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t2.lesson
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE t1.lessonType = t2.lessonType
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS lessonText
FROM yourTable t1
GROUP BY
    t1.lessonType
```

## Demo